# Saving pineapple plant

Tags: plant-health, indoors, plant-care

All my pineapple plants leaves turned yellow, and drying in about a month. My mother most likely over watered it, about 2-3 times a week. It currently has a fruit which is completely yellow now. How can I save it and grow new leaves??  Thanks a million![image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do have 6x "ratoon suckers" already removed from the mother plant and one is still attached but not visible from that angle. It was just said to see the mother plant dying... Unfortunately the plant was store bought and the fruit was labeled not edible. But gorgeous!

Comment: Glad that you removed the ratoons already and can have more pineapples. Too bad you can't eat the one on the mother plant, though.

Answer (score 2):

Pineapples die after fruiting, but usually produce suckers beforehand which replace the mother plant. I unfortunately don't see any suckers on your plant. There's more information about the three different types of suckers, and how best to propagate them, [here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/pineapple-plant-after-picking-pineapple-54608.html).

I would eat that lovely pineapple, if were you - the more golden the pineapple, the sweeter the taste.